# 既存システムのearファイル内のjarを参照したい

Tags: java

#### 解決したいこと

既存システムから別のてサブシステムを作成してwarファイルを作成していましたが
どうしても既存システムの機能を使いたくて参照したいのですが
既存システムはearファイル内にjarを格納しており別のwarファイルから参照するようなやり方は可能でしょうか？

やり方がいまいちわかりません、困っております。
どなたかご教授頂けると助かります。

#### 自分で試したこと

クラスパスを自分なりに書いて見て参照しようとしましたが全く手の打ちどころなくて困っております。

Comment: 静的にクラスパスに追加する、つまり`ear`を展開して必要な`jar`を取り出し自分の`war`に取り込む、のが楽なように思われますが、この方法だと駄目な理由が有るのでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
記載が漏れていましたがearファイル内にAPP-INFフォルダというjarファイルより上の階層にシステムプロパティファイルが作成されておりそちらのファイルを参照しているためjarファイル単独で取り出しても使えないのでは？っと思っていました。